# How to add a digit to a number while making sure beforehand that the result will not be greater than _MAX?

Tags: c

I am converting a number string to a number using the old `x = x * 10 + (c - '0')` method, char by char. I know about atoi, strtol, etc...

The problem is that I want to make sure that x will never exceed the maximum possible value the type can handle. But I do want to also support arbitrary max values that are less than e.g. UINT_MAX, but still if you add 1 more char, it would overflow.

The only solution I came up with is to either make x one type greater than the maximum one I want to support, but that doesn't sound good.

Also, since this is not your usual addition, there is more math involved, and testing if `UINT_MAX / 10 > (double) (x + (c - '0') / 10)` seems wrong.

I am inexperienced with this and I'm hoping for some cool math or bitshift trick to make sure that appending the number `c` to number `x` won't be greater than max (which will usually be the maximum allowable type size like UINT_MAX or ULONG_MAX, etc...)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
    max = UINT_MAX;
    unsigned int x;
    char *str = "65536";
    int i;

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0', i++) {
        if (/* ??? test if adding new digit will exceed max ??? */) {
            x = x * 10 + (str[i] - '0');
        }
        else
            break;
    } 

    printf("x = %ud\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//  Will multiplying x by 10 and adding digit d overflow "unsigned int"?
_Bool WillItOverflow(unsigned int x, unsigned int d)
{
    if (x > UINT_MAX/10)
        return 1;
    else if (x == UINT_MAX/10 && d > UINT_MAX - UINT_MAX/10*10)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

A proof follows. Text in `code style` is the value of code (e.g., `37/10` is 3); other mathematical operations are ordinary real arithmetic (37/10 is 3.7).

- Since integer division truncates, `UINT_MAX/10` = (`UINT_MAX`− *r*)/10, where *r* is the remainder of `UINT_MAX` modulo 10. Necessarily, *r* < 10, and note that *r* = `UINT_MAX - UINT_MAX/10*10`.
- If `x` > `UINT_MAX/10`, `x` >= `UINT_MAX/10` + 1 = (`UINT_MAX`−*r*)/10 + 1, so 10•`x` >= `UINT_MAX`-*r*+10, so 10•`x` >=  `UINT_MAX` + 1.
- If `x` = `UINT_MAX/10`, 10•`x`+`d` = 10•((`UINT_MAX`−*r*)/10) + `d` = `UINT_MAX`−*r*+`d`, which clearly is greater than `UINT_MAX` if and only iff `d` > *r*.
- Otherwise, `x` < `UINT_MAX/10`, so `x` ≤ `UINT_MAX/10`−1, so 10•`x`+`d` ≤ 10•((`UINT_MAX`−*r*)/10)−10 + `d` = `UINT_MAX`−*r*−10 + `d`, and −*r*−10+`d` is non-positive since `d` < 10, so 10•`x`+`d` ≤ `UINT_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use gcc compiler you can use builtin functions:

```
 int main() {
    unsigned int x = 0, tmp, tmp2;
    char *str = "4294967296";
    while(*str)
    {
        if(!__builtin_umul_overflow (x, 10, &tmp) && !__builtin_uadd_overflow(tmp, *str++ - '0', &tmp2)) 
        {
            x = tmp2;
        }
        else
            break;
    } 
    printf("x = %u\n", x);
}
```

Those functions compile the the very efficient assembly code:
https://godbolt.org/z/xM1959bcd

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to detect integer overflow after it happens, but you can perform simple math to detect it before trying to add the next digit:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int x = 0;
    const char *str = "655360000000";
    int i;
    char cc;

    for (i = 0; (cc = str[i]) >= '0' && cc <= '9'; i++) {
        if (x < UINT_MAX / 10
        ||  (x == UINT_MAX / 10 && cc - '0' <= UINT_MAX % 10)) {
            x = x * 10 + (cc - '0');
        } else {
            /* number is too large */
            x = UINT_MAX;
            break;
        }
    } 
    printf("x = %u\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

This method works for all integer types.

Note however that `unsigned` types do not *overflow*, the arithmetics on unsigned types are defined modulo the maximum value plus one. So you could use a simpler sloppy method (albeit not recommended):

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int x = 0;
    const char *str = "655360000000";
    int i;
    char cc;

    for (i = 0; (cc = str[i]) >= '0' && cc <= '9'; i++) {
        unsigned int x0 = x;
        x = x * 10 + (cc - '0');
        if (x < x0) {
            /* number is too large */
            x = UINT_MAX;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("x = %u\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```